# How to pass custom variables to pm2 from command line

Tags: node.js, pm2

#### Passing custom variables to my node application - works

**dist/index.js**

```
const yargs = require("yargs");
console.log(yargs.argv.myvar); // helloworld
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "start": "node dist",
  "pm2": "pm2-runtime start dist"
}
```

**cmd as node** - works

```
npm start -- --myvar=helloworld
```

**cmd as pm2** - fails

```
npm run pm2 -- --myvar=helloworld
```

> Error: error: unknown option `--myvar'